# How do you make images wobble like on the iPhone home screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation

I have many icons in my app and I would like to animate them in a manner similar to what happens when you try to delete applications from the iPhone's home screen.  How can you do this?

Additionally, is there a way to have the icons animate up onto the screen in a manner similar to what happens when you unlock the iPhone?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to make your views, images, etc. wobble, like the home screen, you could do something like this:

```
    CGAffineTransform leftWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(-15.0));
    CGAffineTransform rightWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(15.0));

    view.transform = leftWobble;  // starting point

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"wobble" context:view];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5]; // adjustable
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.125];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    view.transform = rightWobble; // end here & auto-reverse
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

You would also need to add this define:

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)
```

Comment: where should i put this code in viewDidUnload()method or any other as i really dont have idea about this thank you

Comment: You would put it where you needed the animation to start.  For example, if the animation starts when the view is shown, you could do it in the viewWillAppear: method (don't forget to call the superclass method). If you want a UIImage (or any other class of UIView) to wobble, that would be the 'view' specified in the code.

Comment: thank u for quick reply,,its working fine too...but i am looking for something fine animation like screen start from small to full screen like zoom in to zoom out or some diagonal animation as we are doing in ppt presentation..i hope u getting me ..pls help me if u know this thing thank you

Comment: Within the animation block, instead of transform, you would place the animating effect you want.  For example, you could resize a UIImageView from small size to full screen.  Set the frame of the view before the animation block to the initial size then place the new size in the animation block where view.transform... is located.  Depending on what you need you might also use a UIScrollView to handle zooming with touches.

Answer (score 10):

with blocks (iOS 4+) it would look like:

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)

    CGAffineTransform leftWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(-2.0));
    CGAffineTransform rightWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(2.0));

    cell.transform = leftWobble;  // starting point
    cell.deleteButton.hidden = NO;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.125 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse) animations:^{
        cell.transform = rightWobble;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
    }];
```

Comment: I think 2 things could be added. | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction if the button is a child of the view running the animation. // remove the wobble animation for whatever reason
    [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]; importing #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Answer (score 1):

If you mean icons in the main screen of iOS, I don't think it would be ever possible.

Of course, if you mean icons inside your application, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: If the icon simply moves, rotates or scales (like wiggling), then UIKit provides enough functionality for you to do it. Make an UIView (possibly an UIImageView) object for each icon, and make changes of its frame property within an animation block using UIView's class method `animateWithDuration`. An example is in Listing 4-1 and 4-2 of Apple's View Programming Guide for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Answers seem a little outdated, so here's updated logic within an easy to use UIView extension.

Default value for duration parameter being that the animation happens for infinity.

**Swift 5 -2022**

```
extension UIView {
    func wobble(duration: CFTimeInterval = .infinity) {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
        animation.duration = 0.2
        animation.values = [0.015, 0.03, 0.015, 0, -0.015, -0.03, -0.015, 0]
        animation.repeatDuration = duration
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "wobble")
    }

    func layerremoveAllAnimations() {
        layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```