# Animate image like deleting Apps from iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton

I have a ScrollView with several UIButtons (custom type). The UIButtons are shown as Images. I made it to subclass UIButton to shoot an event if the user taps on a button for a long time (approx. 3 seconds).

If a user tap's one of the subclassed UIButtons i thought about animating the selected UIButton the way the apps are animated if you want to delete them.

I have nearly no experiance with animations. Is there something somebody can point me to? All i've found was transitions, but thats not what i need.

Comment: First answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980122/animation-of-icons-in-iphone-app

Comment: If you put your comment as an answer in this post I'll accept it! Thanks for the link. Solved my requirements.

Comment: Ack, it converted to a comment!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make images wobble like on the iPhone home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980122/how-do-you-make-images-wobble-like-on-the-iphone-home-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Ill rephrase) On SO, there are quite a few questions to answer this.  One of then is this link [How do you make images wobble like on the iPhone home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980122/animation-of-icons-in-iphone-app)

Comment: If your answer is "look at the answer to this other question" then the question should be closed as a duplicate, not answered.

Comment: please look at the comments section.  I was told to post that 'duplicate answer' schpeel as an answer to be accepted.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you were asked to do it, the question is still a dupe, you should have flagged it as such. The OP still gets their answer, SO has one less dupe.

Comment: Seriously though, I assume my first comment would have covered what you're asking.  I'll flag it now, if only it'll satisfy your last requirement